# PHP prints text instead of HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type 'Book' and two custom fields Author and Rate. Rate can go from 1 to 5 and I want to print font awesome star icon as many times as number of rate field is. But when I echo font awesome icon it prints only text, not the icon itself.

Code:

```
<div class="book">
        <h3>“<?php the_title(); ?>”</h3>
        <p><?php the_field('author'); ?></p>
        <?php 
            for ($i = 0; $i < the_field('rate'); $i++)
                echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
        ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Need you to provide your custom functions (`the_title()`, `the_field()`) also, we can't verify what they are returning.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a typo. The class should be "fa fa-star"

```
<div class="book">
        <h3>“<?php the_title(); ?>”</h3>
        <p><?php the_field('author'); ?></p>
        <?php 
            for ($i = 0; $i < the_field('rate'); $i++)
                echo '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
        ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the_field function. It immediately prints number so when for iteration starts function prints value and loop stops. I replaced the_field with get_field function which returns value and now it's working!